# Exclude a file from a CODEOWNER file having global owners

Tags: github, github-codeowners

I have a file structure like this:

```
       repo/
       |-- .github/CODEOWNERS 
       |-- .circleci/ 
       |-- app/ 
       |-- RELEASE.md
       |-- README.md
```

And my CODEOWNER file:

```
* @people1 @people2
/.circleci/ @people3 @people4
/app/ @people3 @people1
```

I want to make it to that `RELEASE.md` is excluded and the global owners review are not mandatory only for that file. Is this possible?

Comment: So, for RELEASE.md, you want *no* assigned code owners?

Comment: Yes, that exactly, to have no codeowner required despite having made changes to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mention the file explicitly with no owners, which overrides the `*` pattern (last most specific match counts):

```
* @people1 @people2
/.circleci/ @people3 @people4
/app/ @people3 @people1
RELEASE.md
```